# Send list of list of objects with retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
DateFormat formatoFechaOrden = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm");

    String restaurantId=getIntent().getStringExtra("restaurantId");

    String dateValue =formatoFechaOrden.format(hora.getTime());

    List<List<Meal>> mealsClientes = obtenerListasAlimentos();

    Boolean reservationStatus= false;

    int clients = listaCliente.size();

    Boolean onPlace=getIntent().getBooleanExtra("onPlace",false);

    String remarques = tvRemarques.getText().toString();

    User user = new User(session.getUserDetails().get("id"),session.getUserDetails().get("email"),session.getUserDetails().get("name"));

    List<List<Integer>>howMany = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Meal> menus = (List<Meal>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("menus");
```

I have the follows variables that i want to send, i have tryied with GSON sending all in an objects, but is not working , how can i send List>meals with retrofit2 ????

```
    Order order = new Order(restaurantId,dateValue,mealsClientes,user,reservationStatus,clients,howMany,b,menus,onPlace,remarques,priceLeftToPay);


Call<ResponseBody> call = service.createOrder(order);



 @POST("createOrder?token=FYfZ%2Fo28Mva6MGYnFOdiSOPPdVwSbTuYd86P3wYlq%2Fb5CDqHJwUgQKX5aALSiBP4XQC3TswG8I37%2F4K62ZUnx11n3MIc7sckbDCs8kFbbDMbuql8p0chLLHV20FLu90DfyCSkSvP9D2NAHgNAF8jk76%2B717S2qo%2F7XCw7QQtxIc%3D")
    Call<ResponseBody>createOrder(@Body Order order);
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What exactly is being sent?

Comment: @EdsonMenegatti The Api Rest is responding with error 400 , bad request . Its not receiving data. restaurantId is null , but restaurantId is fine before send.

Comment: So what makes you think the issue is with the list? Regardless, do you have the json that is sent to your server?